# async_request_update() example in SystemC

Tags: c++, systemc

I could not find a complete example code of `async_request_update()`. Can anyone please post a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <systemc>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace sc_core;

class ThreadSafeEventIf : public sc_interface {
    virtual void notify(sc_time delay = SC_ZERO_TIME) = 0;
    virtual const sc_event &default_event(void) const = 0;
protected:
    virtual void update(void) = 0;
};

class ThreadSafeEvent : public sc_prim_channel, public ThreadSafeEventIf {
public:
    ThreadSafeEvent(const char *name = ""): event(name) {}

    void notify(sc_time delay = SC_ZERO_TIME) {
        this->delay = delay;
        async_request_update();
    }

    const sc_event &default_event(void) const {
        return event;
    }
protected:
    virtual void update(void) {
        event.notify(delay);
    }
    sc_event event;
    sc_time delay;
};

SC_MODULE(Foo)
{
public:
    SC_CTOR(Foo)
    {
        SC_THREAD(main);

        SC_METHOD(eventTriggered);
        sensitive << event;
        dont_initialize();
    }
private:
    void main() {
        usleep(5 * 1000 * 1000); // Just for the example, event is added to pending events during this sleep
        wait(SC_ZERO_TIME); // Schedule (event is evaluated here)
        usleep(1 * 1000 * 1000); // Just for the example
        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }

    void eventTriggered() {
        std::cout << "Got event" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    ThreadSafeEvent event;
};

void *externalHostThread(void *arg) {
    usleep(2 * 1000 * 1000); // Just for the example
    Foo* foo = (Foo*)(arg);
    foo->event.notify();
    std::cout << "Event notified from an external host thread" << std::endl;
}

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo("foo");

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, externalHostThread, &foo);

    sc_start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Could you please explain Foo* foo = (Foo*)(arg);

Comment: As pthread argument is a void*, I required to cast it to Foo* to access Foo class attributes. It was one option to access the event but there are many other ways. It is an example :)

Comment: Just want to make sure that I understood it right. so,  (Foo*)(arg); is actually a type casting? and pointer foo in the  externalHostThread points to the instance of FOO in the main()?

Comment: Is it thread safe, if multiple pthreads are notifying at the same time?

Comment: Yes it is thread safe.

Comment: Just curious! How does this work? There is no mutex and also no queue involved. apologies in advance (newbie to C++).

Comment: There is a mutex for the queue of pending events to evaluate in SystemC kernel (at least in the Accellera implementation).

Comment: The event is only triggered once with the largest sc_time even if I try to trigger it with 3 different pthreads. It skips other events.

Comment: By event, I mean timed notification. notify(10,SC_NS)